# @CacheEvit key expression read argument as array of object instead a type

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am doing a cached service, but when I try adding evict, I get the error

```kotlin
    @CacheEvict(value = ["person", "persons"], key = "#person.id")
    suspend fun save(person: Person) {
        personRepository.save(person)
    }
```

```
EL1008E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.Object[]' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

If change to

```kotlin
    @CacheEvict(value = ["person", "persons"], key = "#person[0].id")
    suspend fun save(person: Person) {
        personRepository.save(person)
    }
```

It works fine... But I don't know why...

Why SplEx read person as array of objects?